# Java swing - button's note when the mouse touches it

Tags: java, swing, button, tooltip, mouseevent

I am trying to add a kind of label when the mouse touches a button, I used Jlabel but i failed to create it.

Can you help me?

Comment: what piece of code is not working? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Do you want add a new `JLabel` to your GUI after click `JButton`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [setToolTipText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setToolTipText%28java.lang.String%29) with Button.

```
 button.setToolTipText("Click me");
```

Look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).